# Implement NSURLSession delegate methods in NSObject class

Tags: objective-c

I am facing a problem in my NSObject class when I am try to implement the delegates methods of NSURLSession. The delegates method not called when ever I am try to get the response. I am using the method given below

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config=[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSesh dataTaskWithRequest:req];
defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self  delegateQueue:nil];
[dataTask resume];
```

How to change my code for calling the delegate methods.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating the session (unnecessarily) twice and calling the data task on the *wrong* session without delegate set.

Create the session only once **with** setting the delegate:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

NSURLSession *defaultSesh = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [defaultSesh dataTaskWithRequest:req];
[dataTask resume];
```